How to enable "Modern Authentication" for MS-Office Outlook 2021 Pro?
Microsoft, on Sep. 26, 2024, will no longer support "Basic Authentication" to access any Outlook account -- they will require using "Modern Authentication".
I am trying to understand their instructions found in the following article:
Modern Authentication Methods now needed to continue syncing Outlook Email in non-Microsoft email apps
My configuration is Win-10 Pro, Office 2021 Pro, using Outlook 2021 Pro. I have 4+ email addresses using a combination of Gmail and Comcast addresses.
Around June 10th, I started encountering random, but repeating requests to reenter my email/password, but only for the Comcast addresses. My searching found the article above, and acknowledged the known issue of repeated password requests.
I have a long list of articles I found and have tried their recommendations with no success.
Here is what I have tried:

The article states: "Option 1: Get a newer Outlook email app which supports Modern Authentication
If your Outlook client does not support Modern Authentication, you will need to upgrade to the latest version and then setup using Outlook.com Sync. You can either purchase a new Outlook License, use the Outlook that is included in your Microsoft 365 subscription, or download Outlook for Windows for free." Misinformation from an online chat with Microsoft told me I needed to upgrade from 2016 Pro to newer version, so I purchased 2021 Pro before finding that false (and no refund since digital download!)
Multiple articles state the need to add / change Registry Key:  Modern Authentication configuration requirements for transition from Office 365 dedicated/ITAR to vNextHKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover and set DWORD value to 1. I did that, plus three other keys mentioned in another article.
Is it possible that the Registry Key changes are intended for the Exchange server rather than my PC?
Another search found that Xfinity (Comcast) states they support "Modern Authentication", but no mention of my needing to change anything on their end.
Other articles mention "Outlook.com", but I don't use that.
How to Check Outlook Using Basic or Modern Authentication Connect to Microsoft 365    was useless as the column "Authn" in my Outlook Connections is all blank.
I downloaded and installed the "New Outlook", but was really disappointed, so I uninstalled.

Having found articles on implementing "Modern Authentication" that are 4+ years old, I was hoping I could figure this out. Now I need your help!

I think you want to explore this option of using Outlook desktop app with Gmail accounts: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en. You will need to configure your Gmail account to use these beforehand.

Thank you for your suggestion. However, my Gmail accounts don't seem to have a problem, and my 'critical' accounts are the Comcast/Xfinity ones. I will try to see if I can find any differences in the settings between Gmail and Xfinity..

Consider calling Comcast/Xfinity and ask their technical support for assistance if this is your Internet Service Provider. They should be able to confirm that Outlook 2021 works to connect to their mail servers for your account, and also give guidelines or best practices on connecting Outlook 2021 to their systems.

Here is their guide for Outlook but looks like Outlook from a Mac rather than Windows: https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/configure-outlook-express-xfinity-internet?view=app but also read over this for account level settings you might already control: https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/third-party-email-access

Thank you again for your assistance. I had found the two links you shared, and have configured  to their suggestions. A couple hours ago I was able to have a chat session with a Microsoft agent. Their take is I have no problem because (1) the article I found was  "...syncing Outlook Email in non-Microsoft email apps"; (2) Comcast/Xfinity is not an 'App', it's a 'provider'.  Thunderbird would be an app.  Not sure I trust that conclusion since many articles suggest checking settings in Outlook. I plan to install Thunderbird just to see what happens. Thanks again!
